# Why can an electric chargeless Z-particle decay in three photons?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, electroweak

The Z-particle that is supposed to convey the weak force has no electrical charge. So how is it possible the particle can decay in three photons. Because the weak and e.m. force are more or less artificial unified?

Comment: You're right that the Z boson doesn't interact with photons. But both Z bosons and photons can interact with, say, W bosons, so the decay can proceed like 1) Z decays to two virtual W's, 2) the W's emit photons, 3) the W's annihilate each other.

Comment: Natural is now artificial? Is it opposite day, today?

Comment: I say artificial because I think that the weak force isn´t a basic, but a residue force, conveyed by massless, gluon like particles, like the strong force once was thought basic and conveyed by the massive pion (of wich there are also three kinds), and one later found it was conveyed by gluons. So yes, it´s opposite day. Keeps thing going!